# How can I use reference.docx with pandoc

Tags: pandoc

I need a little advice regarding pandoc and the reference.docx template.
I am on a MacBook Pro with pandoc 3.1.11.1.

My User Data directory is: /Users/My_User_Name/.local/share/pandoc

I generated in /Users/My_User_Name/.local/share/ a new directory with mkdir -p .pandoc/templates
I modified the reference.docx document and saved it in .pandoc/templates

I want to use a Markdown file in an Obsidian folder and generate a new .docx file with the following command:
`pandoc my_file.md -o my_file.docx --data-dir=User/My_User_Name/.local/share/.pandoc/templates  --template=reference.docx`

But I receive the following error:
`Could not find data file templates/reference.docx`
I am not sure if I have a data directory error or an error with my command.

Thank you very much.
Sebastian

Comment: see the [`--reference-doc` option](https://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#option--reference-doc), `--template` is something else..

Comment: yes. i did this: To produce a custom reference.docx, first get a copy of the default reference.docx: pandoc -o custom-reference.docx --print-default-data-file reference.docx. Then open custom-reference.docx in Word, modify the styles as you wish, and save the file. But where do I save the file? in .pandoc/templates or in .pandoc? Thanks

Comment: Either put it the user data directory (e.g. `~/.local/share/pandoc/reference.docx`) or easier, just in the same directory as the input file (`my_file.md)`, then you can do: `pandoc my_file.md -o my_file.docx --reference-doc reference.docx`

Comment: yes, the second solution is working. But I want to use a given directory for my reference.docx. So I tried: pandoc my_file.md -o my_file.docx --reference-doc=~/.local/share/pandoc/reference.docx --from=markdown+hard_line_breaks            
But I get this error: File ~/.local/share/pandoc/reference.docx not found in resource path

Comment: if you have a file at `--reference-doc=~/.local/share/pandoc/reference.docx`, you shouldn't need to use the `--reference-doc` flag at all. pandoc should pick it up and use it as the default...

Comment: yes, I found a solution for my: pandoc my_file.md -o my_file.docx --reference-doc=/Users/My_User_Name/.local/share/pandoc/reference.docx --from=markdown+hard_line_breaks

Comment: Is it possible to point to a reference file located on a website (like SharePoint)? Thank you.

Comment: yes, it's right there in in the linked MANUAL: `--reference-doc=FILE|URL`

Comment: It tried this comand with a reference-doc on github: 

pandoc my-file.md --reference-doc https://github.com/my-github-repository/pandoc-reference-doc/blob/a49e394587f34e2d63c71b489f360a48bb6dacc5/normseite.docx -o my-file.docx 

But I received the following error message: 

Data.Binary.Get.runGet at position 4: Did not find end of central directory signature CallStack (from HasCallStack):
  error, called at libraries\binary\src\Data\Binary\Get.hs:345:5 in binary-0.8.9.1:Data.Binary.Get

Comment: maybe because that link results in a 404? or that's not the real link? otherwise try googling for "Did not find end of central directory signature" – probably means the docx file is corrupted and not a valid zip file